# Group-specific ID numbers using group_indices or similar in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to group a series of observations by two columns, and then create a third column with an id number. I've tried `group_indices`, but that gives each combination of observations a unique number. I want the number to revert to `1` for the first observation of each group.

In my data there are a series of `Sites` with a number of rows showing the calendar `Day` when an observation was collected. I want to calculate the chronological day *within* a `Site`.

```
library(dplyr)

# Make some data
df <- data.frame(Site = rep(c("A", "B", "C"), each = 70),
            Day = as.integer(rep(c(21,22,23,24,25,26,27,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,
                      24,25,26,27,28,29,30), each = 10)))

# Create Day Number column (this doesn't actually work, but is the sort
# of thing I'm looking for...)
df <- df %>% group_by(Site, Day) %>% 
                mutate(Day.Number = group_indices(Day))

# Desired output
     Site Day Day.Number
1      A  21     1
2      A  21     1
3      A  21     1
...
11     A  22     2
12     A  22     2
13     A  22     2
14     A  22     2
15     A  22     2
...
141    C  24     1
142    C  24     1
143    C  24     1
144    C  24     1
...
151    C  25     2
152    C  25     2
153    C  25     2
154    C  25     2
155    C  25     2
...
```

This is just a toy dataset to demonstrate the problem. Although most `sites` will have ten observations of seven `days` it is not always a given, so I can't just use a sequence of `rep()` etc.

There is a bit of a discussion about this on github [here](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/2160) and [here](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/1185) but it doesn't seem to have been resolved. Any suggestions for workarounds are much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one way to do it:

```
df <- df %>% 
        left_join(unique(df) %>% group_by(Site) %>% mutate(Day.Number=1:n()))

head(df)
#   Site Day Day.Number
# 1    A  21          1
# 2    A  21          1
# 3    A  21          1
# 4    A  21          1
# 5    A  21          1
# 6    A  21          1
```

Comment: I get the following; `Error in rank(x, ties.method = "first", na.last = "keep") : argument "x" is missing, with no default`

Comment: Somewhat peculiar... I get the intended result when simply using `row_number()`, but when I specify `dplyr::row_number()` I get the same error you do. I updated `dplyr` and restarted my session to no avail; it seems the issue may be related to [this closed issue](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/2792). `1:n()` can be used as an alternative to `row_number()`.

Comment: Weird - specifying `dplyr` made the the error go away in my case... Anyway, your answer works nicely with the example data. My real data has many more columns, so all rows are unique. Then it just gives the row number as the output. So as a workaround I subsetted out the `Site` and `Day` columns, used your code, and then just added the new `Day.Number` column back onto the main dataframe. Thanks for your help!